# Can't display hosted images in AMP site

Tags: javascript, html, image, accelerated-mobile-page

I'm creating a basic AMP site, after the *XMLHttpRequest* that loads the product details I change the web content using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("stock").innerHTML = result.ref
```

This is the right approach for this new framework?

But what about the images? It recognises only the `<amp-img>` ID tag, not it child (standard `<img>`).

I've tried this way with no success:

```
document.getElementById("stock").src = "PATH_TO_MY_SITE" + result.ref + ".png"
```

It shows this error: `Either non-empty "srcset" or "src" attribute must be specified:`

Comment: Does `console.log("PATH_TO_MY_SITE" + result.ref + ".png")` produce a valid image url?

Comment: Yes, it shows the right url, I've tried it. I've added a console error at the end of my question

Comment: Do you load it originally with an empty `src` attribute and update the DOM with JS later? Maybe it's complaining about the original empty/non-existent src attribute on page load? When you say **it** shows this error - what is **it**?

Comment: The error was: `Either non-empty "srcset" or "src" attribute must be specified:`, I've added a "default image", but still doesn't show the "dynamic" image